# how to use autocomplete with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

im using autocomplete of jqueryui (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)
and the source comes from "source: "search.php""

This code ...

```js
 $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
```

.. And this code below together works perfectly fine!
but autocomplete suggest me "All of my Data" ! not smth like my term.

```
<?php
require('inc/tunel.php');
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$respons = array();
$fetch_engine = $db->query("SELECT name FROM `engine`");
    while($read_engine = $fetch_engine->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $respons[] = $read_engine['name'];
        }

        echo json_encode($respons);
 ?>
```

i also tried this code below, my problem solved, but i dont want to see my data in "view source" of my document!

```js
$( "#name" ).autocomplete({
source: <?php
 require('inc/tunel.php');

 $respons = array();
 $fetch_engine = $db->query("SELECT name FROM `engine`");
  while($read_engine = $fetch_engine->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $respons[] = $read_engine['name'];
   }
   
   echo json_encode($respons);
   

?>,
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
```

Comment: have you read the manual for Remote Datasource - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote?

Comment: yeah but what does "search.php" return? an array?

Comment: [The datasource is a server-side script which returns JSON data](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) and the API for `source` - http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source. So you could do `$respons=array(); $fetch_engine = $db->query("SELECT name FROM `engine`"); while($read_engine = $fetch_engine->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $respons[] = $read_engine['name'];}echo json_encode($respons);`

Comment: And if you want to include the `term`, it could be like `$fetch_engine = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM engine WHERE name LIKE ?"); $db->execute(array($_GET['term'])`, assuming `$db` is PDO

Comment: @Sean
can you check it again please?

Comment: Try changing `$fetch_engine = $db->query("SELECT name FROM \`engine\`");` to `$fetch_engine = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM \`engine\` name LIKE :name"); $fetch_engine->execute(array(':name'=>"%".$_GET['term']."%"));`. This way you only select the rows that are similar to your term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a local service that accepts a parameter with a substring (in my example parameter q with at least 2 chars) and returns a json with the possible tags, and then use it into the source of the autocomplete as an ajax call.

```
    $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
          source: function( request, response ) {
           $.ajax({
              url: "http://yourwebservice.com/search",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              data: {
                q: request.term
              },
              success: function( data ) {
                response( data );
              }
            });
          },
          minLength: 2
        });
```

Comment: can you check it again please?